# Get all users in the Active Directory

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, active-directory

I am trying to get a list of all users in the active directory on a domain. The following code is being used but doesn't seem to work:

```
Public Function GetAllUsers(ByVal ldapServerName As String) As Hashtable
    'To retrieve list of all  LDAP users

    'This function returns HashTable
    _ldapServerName = ldapServerName

    Dim sServerName As String = "mail"

    Dim oRoot As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" & ldapServerName & _
          "/ou=People,dc=mydomainname,dc=com")

    Dim oSearcher As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(oRoot)
    Dim oResults As SearchResultCollection
    Dim oResult As SearchResult
    Dim RetArray As New Hashtable()

    Try

        oSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("uid")
        oSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("givenname")
        oSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn")
        oResults = oSearcher.FindAll

        For Each oResult In oResults

            If Not oResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties("cn").Value = "" Then
                RetArray.Add(oResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties("uid").Value, _
                  oResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties("cn").Value)
            End If

        Next

    Catch e As Exception

        'MsgBox("Error is " & e.Message)
        Return RetArray

    End Try

    Return RetArray

End Function
```

Just to make sure I am doing this correctly, the `ldapServerName` should be the domain name that I log into that I see when I <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>, correct? Or would that go into the `dc=mydomainname` part?

The first error in that code above is on `_ldapServerName = ldapServerName`

The error is says is:

```
 Error 14 '_ldapServerName' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

**marc_s update**

```
    ' create a domain context for your default domain
    Dim ctx As New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)

    ' define a "query-by-example" to search for
    Dim searchExample As Principal = New UserPrincipal(ctx)

    ' define the principal searcher, based on that example principal
    Dim ps As New PrincipalSearcher(searchExample)

    ' loop over all principals found by the searcher
    For Each p As Principal In ps.FindAll()
        ' do whatever you want to do with the principals
        Console.WriteLine("Type: {0} / Name: {1}", p.StructuralObjectClass, p.Name)
    Next
```

**update 2**

When I use IE and input `ldap://mydomainhere.com/ou=Users`

I do not get anything... But when I just do this:

```
 ldap://mydomainhere.com
```

Then I get the "find people" box pop up. So I know I have the correct `LDAP` but not sure why the other information is preventing it from working...

Comment: So where are you actually declaring `_ldapServerName`, and what's the use of this variable; it's not used in your code!?

Comment: Ok, i took it out and there are no errors now but i do not get any value. I get the error: Error is There is no such object on the server. **How can i find my LDAP?**

Answer (score 2):

If your AD isn't too big, and you're on .NET 3.5 or up (which I assume, since you're using VS2010), you should be able to write something like:

```
// create a domain context for your default domain
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// define a "query-by-example" to search for
Principal searchExample = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

// define the principal searcher, based on that example principal
PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(searchExample);

// loop over all principals found by the searcher
foreach(Principal p in ps.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever you want to do with the principals
    Console.WriteLine("Type: {0} / Name: {1}", p.StructuralObjectClass, p.Name);
}
```

**PS:** In order to "find your LDAP", you could have a look at my C#, open-source LDAP browser called [BeaverTail](http://adsi.mvps.org/adsi/CSharp/beavertail.html) - available for free (C#, .NET 1.1 timeframe)

[image]

**Update:** if you want to select all users in a specific location (and its sub-containers), you can do this by specifying that "starting point" in your domain context:

```
// create a domain context for your default domain, 
// starting at a specific location
PrincipalContext ctx = 
   new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN", 
                        "OU=Personnel,OU=Users,DC=YourDomain,DC=com");

// define a "query-by-example" to search for
Principal searchExample = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

// define the principal searcher, based on that example principal
PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(searchExample);

// loop over all principals found by the searcher
foreach(Principal p in ps.FindAll())
{
    UserPrincipal up = (p as UserPrincipal);

    if(up != null)
    {
       // do whatever you want to do with the principals
       Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} / E-Mail: {1}", up.Name, up.EmailAddress);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cant seem to get your code working when converting it to VB. Check OP. Doesnt know what PrincipalContext, UserPrincipal, PrincipalSearcher is.

Comment: @StealthRT: You need to add a reference to the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` assembly (and namespace) - sorry, my bad....

Comment: Ok added but i get this error when running it: **The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist.** on the line of: **Dim ps As New PrincipalSearcher(searchExample)**. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @StealthRT: no works just fine for me.... hmm... is that machine you're running that code on member of that domain you're trying to find the users for??

Comment: @marc_d: Yes, its on the same domain. I can pull up the AD when i want to share a drive letter and it comes up with 300+ users so i know i am on the domain.

Comment: Ok using your program i found my user name under the main LDAP name (where yours says bluenose) and then found all the users under **OU=Personnel** then **OU=Users**. Within that is where it lists all the users with **CN="usernamehere"**. So knowing that, how can i run that to loop and get all those names and email address from each?

Comment: On the **Dim ps As New PrincipalSearcher(searchExample)** line i get the error **A referral was returned from the server.**

Comment: If the AD store is huge, say over 100K users, will FindAll get them all back once (in memory)?

Comment: @PerlDev: by default, there is a limit at about 1'000 objects - however, you can enable "paging" by setting the `PageSize` property to a value other than 0, and then you get all the data - one page at a time (so you don't have all the data in memory at one time - you get it in manageable chunks)

Answer (score 1):

```
CStr(userlist(i).Properties("samAccountName").ToString)
```

Change to:

```
userlist(i).GetDirectoryEntry().Properties("givenName").Value
```

That change worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In my particular instance, I had to use:

```
Dim oRoot As DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=Users,DC=YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME_HERE,DC=local")
```

Comment: So you didn't have to put anything for LDAP://{here}?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!